# Properties of isomorphism in module theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I have two exercises, but I can't solve them:

a. If $X, A, B $ are $R$-modules with $A \subset B \subset X $, prove that if $X/A \cong X/B$ then $A=B$

b. If $X/A \cong X$ then $A=0$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @user37238 It's difficult trying to prove wrong statements.

Answer (score 3):

You can't solve them because the statements are false.

For (b) the counterexample is the [Prüfer $p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$, for which
$$
\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)/A\cong \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)
$$
for every proper subgroup $A$.

Of course this also gives counterexamples to (a), because $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ has infinitely many subgroups and they form a chain.